# Symfony 3 Routing allowing hyphes/dashes in placeholder value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I am having an issue with a route in Symfony, I have a route setup that needs to match the below:

```
/my-test-route-holidays/
```

The above "my-test-route" is the placeholder variable.

The route in symfony is as follows:

```
overview:
  path: /{var}-holidays/
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Overview:index }
```

Symfony cannot find the route, a route like below does work without dashes/hyphens in the variable:

```
/test-holidays/
```

So my question is, how can I allow hyphens inside a route placeholder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this myself, it was a quick skim of the documentation that led me to the wrong answer.

I come across this page on Symfonys website a few times whilst trying to research the answer: [Symfony Docs Current Slash in Parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

In their example:

```
share:
    path:     /share/{token}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:share }
    requirements:
        token: .+
```

You can see that they have added "requirements" and underneath that "token", I just assumed that "token" was something to do with regex but actually it relates to the placeholder you have in your "path" and they should match.

Below is what I had:

```
overview:
  path: /{var}-holidays/
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Overview:index }
  requirements:
      token: .+
```

But what I actually needed was to replace the "token" under "requirements" with "var".

```
overview:
  path: /{var}-holidays/
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Overview:index }
  requirements:
      var: .+
```

And what do you know, it works!

I hope somebody else finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `.+` as it will match "any" character including `/` slash characters, used to separate routes.  
eg: `/@nY-th1nG/can/../~/go$foo-holidays`

Since the `requirements` parameter accepts a regular expression, for matching the hyphens I recommend using `[-\w]+` instead. Which matches `-a-zA-Z0-9_` 1 or more times.

```
overview:
  path: /{var}-holidays/
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Overview:index }
  requirements:
      var: [-\w]+
```

### Example https://3v4l.org/c712H

Allowing

```
/01234578247-AbC-19082-Zx-holidays
```

Excluding paths like `/$-holidays` or `/test/12-holidays`

---

If you're expecting only digit dates, you could use `[-\d]+` or for a more strict requirement on the accepted date formats `\d{1,4}(-\d{1,2})?`. 0-9999 followed by optional dash and 0-99

```
overview:
  path: /{var}-holidays/
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Overview:index }
  requirements:
      var: [-\d]+ #or \d{1,4}(-\d{1,2})?
```

Which will allow

```
/190-holidays
/190-02-holidays
```

Excluding paths like `/2019-a-holidays` and `/a-2019-holidays`

If you need a specific format let me know and I will update the requirement pattern used to one that is more appropriate.